# Is it possible to ignore a column mapping contitionally in code first Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I am currently using Entity Framework to connect to two databases with almost the same schema. I generated the code first classes from the database with all of the tables and columns. I was just wondering if there was a way to return null for a column that may be missing (and not get a mapping error) and return a value for the database that still has that column? I don't want to just ignore the mapping for that property because I want the value from the database that still has that column.

Comment: This sounds like kind of a XY problem. Why do you need to target databases with different schemas with the same model? You might have to detect the "version" of the DB schema somehow and then dynamically adjust the mapping in Code First depending on that.

Comment: I simplified the problem in my example. There are actually many databases (one per project) and versions due to the software allowing the user to add user defined fields (it adds columns). I always know the latest schema but older versions are missing some fields. It may be that EF is not the best solution given this issue but I thought I would see what was possible. I have one service that will get data out of a specific database and I was trying to use one context (passing in different connection strings).

Comment: Honestly, your use case sounds sort of rare, and would require EF doing essentially the same as I'm proposing you do yourself - sniff the database metadata and optionally add a column mapping depending on that. I find it unlikely this is available in the framework.

Comment: You will also have to pass different mapping set to your context constructor - each will reflect the database you are going to use.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think I am just going to have to roll my own code to deal with my unique situation.